# Printing ZPL command file from web application

Tags: html, web, printing, zpl

I'm calling a webService (from La Poste in France) in my WebApp that sends me batch of ZPL commands to print labels.

I would like to be able to print directly this set of commands to my Zebra printer from this web application ?

Question : is it possible and how ? Will it work by creating a generic text driver and printer the set of commands to the printer as I've read on Internet (https://www.foldermill.com/kb/install-generic-text-driver-in-windows for example)

For the moment, I do not have any printer to do a test and check it, so this question.

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you get valid ZPL from the web service this should work as you have suggested. Printing ZPL commands via generic text driver works 100%! You can test the received commands on webservice labelary.com

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, using the print function of my browser with the generic text driver on a document containing only zpl commands does not work.
It seems the page is not sent only in text.

To achieve my goal (print from a web page), I have developed an agent installed on the computer that communicate with websockets with my web page.